# create and open a sample pdf file while inside the application

Tags: android

I want to open a pdf file when inside the application(internal storage).I have the following code.But once adobe pdf is opened it shows a pop up error as " The document path is not valid".Is it not possible to only read a pdf file from inside the app? If not please let me know how can I copy it to the external storage.Thanks in advance

```
File file_source = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/"+"sample.pdf");
                String string = "Hello world!";
                try
                {
                    file_source.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream outputStream;
                    outputStream = openFileOutput("sample.pdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                    if(file_source.exists())
                    {
                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file_source);
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent1.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        try {
                            startActivity(intent1);
                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, 
                                    "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            startActivity(intent2);


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG","no file exists");

                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("TAG","File not found");
                }
                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.d("TAG","Exception while reading file" + ioe);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Files in the internal storage directory of your app are by default private to your application. Which means that no PDF-Reader app can read that file (since it doesn't run with your apps pid - no read permission is given).

You have to save that PDF with explicit reading permissions for other apps by using the Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE flag.

Also use Context.openFileOutput() and Context.openFileInput() to read and write files in your internal directory . Don't hardcode paths like this, they might change.

You can copy the file from internal storage to external storage by below code.

```
try {
            String file_name="inputpdf.pdf";
            File tempfile = new File(directory, file_name);
            FileInputStream     inStream = new FileInputStream(tempfile);
            //where ctx is your context (this)
            FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput("Outputpdf", ctx.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE|ctx.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);

                }

                inStream.close();
                fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: hi I did the following.But the pdf file is always saying "The document is empty".There is something wrong with the copying from internal to external storage.Please help

Comment: what is the output file extension.please check if .pdf is missing then change the 'Outputpdf' to 'Outputpdf.pdf'

Comment: Hey Chandra thanks I am able to open the pdf file now.the issue was I was giving wrong "outputpdf" path which should be Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.....